# Android app that lets you do freehand transform

Tags: android, android-app

I nees to use free hand transform tool (take a corner and strech outside canvas) on android. I distinctly remember doing so in the past, with some full blown photo editor app, but cant seem to find it. Lightroom, photoshop express, pixlr, snapseed, camera zoom fx do not have the function that I need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably better asked at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Found it on snapseed. It is called perspective.